# Testing the hostname in a .cshrc

Tags: unix, csh

I would like my .cshrc file to carry out several commands depending on the host I've logged in to (the .cshrc file is on a disk that is shared by two different hosts).

Let's assume the two hosts are: login1.university.edu and login2.university.edu

I tried this command:

```
if(hostname == 'login1.university.edu') then
setenv R_LIBS_USER /n/Users/me/R.login1
else
setenv R_LIBS_USER /n/Users/me/R.login2
endif
```

which doesn't work.

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surround the `hostname` command with `backtics` to execute it and compare the result.

```
if(`hostname` == 'login1.university.edu') then
setenv R_LIBS_USER /n/Users/me/R.login1
else
```